# Certain options not taking effect in fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I'm using [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) (which is brilliant), but I haven't been able to get a few of its options to have any effect. For example, the navigation won't appear, nor is the content vertically centered. [Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGBGMp) is a link to the code I am using. These are the options that aren't taking effect so far:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    navigation: true,
    navigationPosition: 'right',
    verticalCentered: true
});
```

If anyone familiar with fullpage.js could take a look it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did never use fullpage.js but I just checked out the source and your example.

This is what I came up with:

- The "navigation" option doesn't work because fullpage.js can't append the section navigation items to the element with the id **#fp-nav**. That's probably because it sets the "nav" selector *before it adds this element to the body*. You can see that it was correct in a previously tagged version: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/v.2.2.8/jquery.fullPage.js vs https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/jquery.fullPage.js

I'm not sure what's up with the "master" branch, but it seems like this is broken (or it only works with a specific version of jQuery).

You could however dirty-fix the navigation problem by adding a

```
<div id="fp-nav"><ul></ul></div>
```

somewhere in your body.

---

The vertical alignment seems to work for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution worked. I'll try and mention this on Github.

Comment: Indeed it is a bug in the latest version. 2.6.7.1. Use 2.6.7 instead. It will be solved in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your settings are being applied, but you are expecting the results to be different. for example, verticalCentered is working as you can tell by inspecting the page and seeing that vertical-align:middle is happening.

[image]

and your navbar is there, just not visible for some reason (maybe you need to pass in more settings? Not sure on this one.)

[image]

I am not sure what you are looking for it to look like exactly, but I would use chrome devtools if you aren't already to help check if things are actually changing.

Comment: Good point, I was confusing a vertical center with a horizontal center.